# How do I send and receive file size before sending the contents in C?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to figure out how to send my file size to the server, and then proceed to send the file contents. So far, i get the 'Error sending file size message' and no other error messages, although I know there is probably a lot wrong. Can someone demonstrate how im meant to send and receive the file size?

Client part(sends the file):

```
else if(putCommand){
            
            char *tmp = buf + 4;
            char filename[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
    
        size_t file_size;
        size_t x;
        size_t y;
            strcpy(filename, "filename ");
            strcat(filename, tmp);
            FILE *fp;
            printf("File name: %s\n", tmp);
            fp = fopen(tmp, "rb");
            if(fp == NULL){
                
                printf("ERROR: Requested file does not exist.\n");
                
            }
            else{
            printf("Client sending filename...\n");
            if ((nw = write(sd, filename, sizeof(filename)) < nr)){     //sending the file name to the client first
                printf("Error sending client's filename.\n");
            }
            
            //size_t file_size;
            printf("Client sending file size...\n");
            
            while((file_size = fread(buf, 1, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE, fp) > 0)){ //sending the file size
            
                if ((x = write(sd, buf, file_size) < nr)){
                    printf("Error sending client file size.\n");
                }
            
            }
            printf("Client sending file contents...\n");
            while((y = fread(buf, 1, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE, fp) > 0)){ //sending the file contents
                
                if((x = write(sd, buf, sizeof(buf)) < nr)){
                    printf("Error sending file contents.\n");
                }
                
            }
            
            fclose(fp);
            
            
            }
          }
```

Server part (receives the file and creates a copy):

```
 if(getFile){
         
                char *tmp = buf + 9;
                char filename2[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
                int length;
                size_t file_size = 0;
                FILE *fp;
                strcpy(filename2, tmp);
                printf("Server receiving file name...\n");
                //first 'read' in a previous statement outside this block receives the file name
                fp = fopen(filename2, "wb");
                if(fp == NULL){
                    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                printf("Server receiving file size...\n");
                if((nr = read(sd, buf + file_size, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE)) <= 0){ //second read now retrieving the file size
                    printf("Error receiving file size.\n");
                }
                
                
                printf("Server receiving file contents...\n");
            if((nr = read(sd, buf, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE)) <= 0){
            
                fwrite(buf, 1, file_size, fp);
                
            }
            fclose(fp);
            printf("The server has received the requested document.\n");
         }
```

Comment: `< nr` On the client side why are you comparing everything against `nr`? You don't show any code that sets that. That's not the number of bytes you are trying to send. So of course it gives that error.

Comment: `Error sending file size message` does not appear anywhere in this code.

Comment: To be able to send the file size you first need to get the file size. `file_size = fread(buf, 1, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE, fp)` that's not the way to get the file size. Use `fseek` to get to the end of the file and then `ftell` to get the file position which is also the size. Then to send it you do `write(sd, &file_size, sizeof(file_size))`. But you may need to deal with endianess.

Comment: @kaylum nr is simply 0, i make it 0 because if there was an error retrieving the bytes it would be satisfied, atleast so far it has. How can I improve that then?

Comment: @ScottHunter It does in my client side, in the first while loop inside the if statement

Comment: @kaylum Okay I will try that

Comment: Also, `((x = write(sd, buf, file_size) < nr))` needs to be `((x = write(sd, buf, file_size)) < nr)`. What you have assigns the result of the `<` comparison into `x` instead of the result of the `write`. Though it doesn't matter in your case as you don't actually use `x`.

Comment: No, it says `Error sending client file size.`, so if your code produces `Error sending file size message`, it is not the same code as posted here.